# softkeyboard pop up while there are no editable widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I meet a problem.when i login my app(from login page to home page),there is no any editable widgets in home page,but the keyboard pops up automatically which i dont want to ,
how to fix it?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/1109108#1109108):

> You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the
>   [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), calling hideSoftInputFromWindow, passing in
>   the token of the window containing your edit field.
>
> ```
> InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
> imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
> ```
>
> This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some
>   cases you will want to pass in `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY`
>   as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the
>   user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) (YourActivity)
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(home.getCurrentFocus()
                            .getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```